# How to get newest api version of Azure Extensions

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-diagnostics

I am lookin for the **newest api version** of VMDiagnosticsSettings and CustomScriptExtension.

I tried to find it via PowerShell with Get-AzureRmResourceProvider but **VMDiagnosticsSettings is an extension and not a Provider**.

Is there any PowerShell command to find the newest extension version of this?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Microsoft Docs says that the information for the configuration should be in Resources array of the Vm config. I don't have an Azure account to test again, but should think you could parse that file with something like `Select-String` or `Get-Content`.

MS Docs link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-diagnostics-template#add-the-azure-diagnostics-extension-to-the-vm-resource-definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VM Extensions are part of Microsoft.Compute.
So you can just use the newest API Version of Compute.

Powershell:

```
(Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Compute).ResourceTypes
```